# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types with Service Fabric

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Problem is pretty simple. I moved a WebApps project to Service Fabric which had the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types nuget package installed. Now, when trying to access database I'm getting the following error because I'm using spatial types.

> "Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found. "

I've tried adding the following line of code to the class which the FabricRuntime creates an instance of, but that was of no use.

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

Your help would be appreciated, please do let me know if you need more info from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need the line of code, but for asp.net application it should be slightly different:
For Asp.net websites, Default.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static bool _isSqlTypesLoaded = false;

    public _Default()
    {
        if (!_isSqlTypesLoaded)
        {
            SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~"));
            _isSqlTypesLoaded = true;
        }

    }
}
```

For web applications, in Global.asax.cs:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
```

Also you need to create the following binding redirect in web.config:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/244) is the only discussion on the topic which helped me.

**Update:** [Here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2017/03/27/solving-spatial-types-and-functions-are-not-available-with-entity-framework/) is a blog post that provides a well described solution in 3 steps. Although, the third step didn't work for me and I had to create the binding as described above.

Comment: Thanks! a minor variation of this fixed my issue, you can find it here: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/369